# Postprocessing data after convolution in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, signal-processing

Please assume that we have the following test signal:

```
import numpy as np
fs = 10000
f1 = 60
duration = 10
samples = int(fs*duration)
t = np.arange(samples) / fs
signal = 15 * t * np.sin(2.0*np.pi*f1*t)
```

from which the RMS value will be calculated using convolution as follows:

```
def calculate_rms(signal, N):
    sig2 = np.power(signal,2)
    window = np.ones(N)/float(N)
    return np.sqrt(np.convolve(sig2, window, 'valid'))

N = (1.0 / f1) * fs
RMS = calculate_rms(signal,N)
```

However, after convolution, `RMS` of course has less data points than `t` and `signal` and I am not sure how to postprocess `t` and `signal` in order to be able to plot them together with `RMS` as `signal=f(t)` and `RMS=f(t)` in the same plot witout distorting the temporal dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

In `np.convolve`, use the mode `'same'` instead of `'valid'` (see [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) for more info). If you do so, `RMS` will have the same shape as `t` and `signal`. There may be boundary effects at the edges, but these will likely be very minor and probably won't affect your plot.

#### Option 2

If you're desperate to keep the result clean of possible boundary effects, you can crop `t` and `signal` to correspond to the region that `RMS` covers. Since the `valid` part of the convolution starts at half of the window size, this can be done as follows.

```
t_cropped = t[int(N)//2:-int(N)//2+1]
signal_cropped = signal[int(N)//2:-int(N)//2+1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Feel free to accept it (if you consider it correct).